# No hint path defined for [xxx]

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to link in my package to a view also in the same package.
This is the file structure:

```
/report/src
/report/src/ReportServiceProvider.php
/report/src/views/test.blade.php
/report/src/SomeClass.php
```

In my `ReportServiceProvider.php` I specify the directory where the views should be loading from (like [specified here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages#views)):

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/views', 'reports');
}
```

With the 'hint' reports, so I should be able to access them with `view('reports::test')`

Off course I add my ServiceProvider to `/config/app.php`'s providers array like so:

```
....
Vendor\Report\ReportServiceProvider::class,
....
```

I load my package in composer as follows:

```
"autoload": {
  ....
  "psr-4": {
     "App\\": "app/",
     "Vendor\\Report\\": "packages/vendor/report/src"
  }
  ...
 }
```

But when I use the `view('reports::test')` in `SomeClass.php` i get the following error:

No hint path defined for [reports]

So somehow it cannot find the reports hint....
What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you dump `__DIR__` within the server provider?

Comment: Hmmm, die('something') does not produce a die, application just gets loaded.... so the serviceprovider might not be loading?

Comment: Indeed that is correct. Just to make sure, create a `register` method in your service provider and then dump something, see if that shows up, otherwise it's not loading your provider, could try a `composer dump-autoload` if you think the path to the provider is correct?

Comment: I must be missing something.... I put defer=false to let it always load; in register() a simple die('hello'); but nothing happens :(

Comment: You also shouldn't need to use the autoload section for custom packages, assuming there are in the vendor directory.

Comment: They are not in the vendor directory, so that's why I'm loading them via the psr-4 method :)

Comment: Ok spitballing here, in the register method of your service provider, try using the facade View. `View::addNamespace('reports', [path(s)])`

Comment: Sorry, but I think that your decision to plase views folder in `src` was inappropriate. Try to move it from `src`.

Comment: @huuuk where he puts them doesn't matter as long as they are loaded correctly.

Comment: @lan I think that cause of the issue is `They are not in the vendor directory, so that's why I'm loading them via the psr-4 method :)`

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue for Laravel's default forgot-password functionality. Error `No hint path defined for [emails]`

Running `php artisan optimize:clear` fixed it for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32254174)

Answer (score 4):

I think **report** is your package name,

**Step 1**: You must specify the package name inside the service provider

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/views', 'report');
```

**Step 2**: If you want to load the view

```
return view('packageName::Email.testmail'); //packageName is report, the actual path to my view is package/report/src/views/Email/testmail.blade.php
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the package' service provider in cofing/app.php

Comment: This worked! Add `VoyagerThemes\VoyagerThemesServiceProvider::class`, to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error `No hint path defined for [view]` by putting the following code snippet on my service provider `boot` method of my package:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/views', 'home');
```

Where `home` is my view file `home.blade.php`. As I am Laravel beginner, maybe in package builded type of coding in need to give the path of view files inside service provider.

Answer (score 0):

if you have your blades views in ...views/xxx, that is how you can specify it:

```
app('xxx')->addNamespace('mail', resource_path('views') . '/xxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `infyomlabs/adminlte-templates` package just add service provider in `config/app.php` as shown below:

```php
'providers' => [
    // ...
    InfyOm\AdminLTETemplates\AdminLTETemplatesServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
],
```

Answer (score 0):

**@include('cookie-consent::index')** this should be used the blade file
either in the body tag or footer tag

```
<body>
@include('cookie-consent::index')
</body> 



<footer>
@include('cookie-consent::index')
</footer>
```

**@include('cookieConsent::index')** /**this might not work */

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).